# Discriminate private member union in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I've got a little problem with discriminating private class members' types. I'm trying to access variables `v1` and `v2` by using string literals, however typescript returns a type union. I managed to solve this by giving typescript a little "push". The bad news is that it works for public members only. See this example below:

```
class Test {
    private v1: string;
    private v2: number;
    v3: string;
    v4: number;
    private v5: string;
    private v6: number;

    // Works for all members, but does not discriminate union
    get12(what: 'v1' | 'v2') {
        return this[what];
    }

    // Works only for public members
    get34<T extends 'v3' | 'v4'>(what: T) {
        return this[what];
    }

    // Explicit overload works, but it defeats the purpose of being lazy
    get56(what: 'v5'): string;
    get56(what: 'v6'): number;
    get56(what: 'v5' | 'v6') {
        return this[what];
    }
}

let myTest = new Test();
myTest.get12('v1'); // returns "string | number" type
myTest.get34('v3'); // returns "string" type
myTest.get56('v5'); // returns "string" type
```

Does anyone know a workaround of some sorts?

**Edit:**
To clarify, I'm looking for a lazy/generic solution. There are other ways I could achieve what I want, however they all require me to maintain them in case variable type changes (for ex., explicit overloading).

Comment: Would explicit overloads work?

Comment: Have you checked out type guards? https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html#user-defined-type-guards Then you could at least narrow the type after the fact

Comment: @vincecampanale I don't really need type guards in this case. Explicit overloading would work, however I'm hoping that someone knows some sort of way to trick typescript to discriminating union like I do for public members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bleggh, this seems to be a [design limitation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17362) of TypeScript, where you can't use indexed access in some situations with private properties.  Not sure how best to navigate this.

Here's something that "works", but *I can't recommend actually doing it*:

```
//@ts-ignore
type UnsafeIndexed<T, K extends string> = T[K]
```

The above is an intentionally bad type alias that asks the compiler to do indexed access even when it can't be sure such a thing will work.  Look at it go:

```
type Foo = { bar: string, baz: number };
type FooBar = UnsafeIndexed<Foo, "bar">; // string
type FooBaz = UnsafeIndexed<Foo, "baz">; // number
type FooBad = UnsafeIndexed<Foo, "nope">; // any
```

Now you can do this:

```
class Test {
    private v1: string;
    private v2: number;

    get<K extends 'v1' | 'v2'>(what: K): UnsafeIndexed<this,K> {
        return (this as any)[what];
    }
}
```

Note you have to do `(this as any)` since `this[what]` still throws a compiler error.  Test it:

```
let myTest = new Test();
const v1 = myTest.get('v1'); // string
const v2 = myTest.get('v2'); // number
```

Okay, that "works", as I said.  But I wouldn't want that touching production code.  I don't know if there's a less evil workaround that is generic.  Personally, I'd either just use public properties or overloads.  Your mileage may vary.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: There is a way to make `UnsafeIndexed` safe (kinda). Take a look at this: `get12(what: 'v1' | 'v2'): UnsafeIndexed<this, typeof what> { return this[what]; }`. If will complain about implicit any if `what` literal does not have a valid property. I think I'll use this solution. If you could edit your answer to include this, I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: But that just returns `string | number` when you call it, which is no improvement over your original `get12()`.  I don't understand why you'd want me to include that.  Could you double check?

Comment: Indeed, it seemed to work, but at the same time I have switched typescript version in VSCODE IDE. It might have cause this false-positive for me.